# php decode data from utf8 to windows-1256

Tags: php, utf-8

I use simplexml_load_file to load user tweets

http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/userid.xml?count=44

I get the data with UTF-8 encoding

How I can convert data to **windows-1256**

Comment: http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding too

Answer (score 1):

```
iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1256//TRANSLIT", $string);
```